# Google clientLogin authentication url responds - 302 The document has moved

Tags: http, authentication

I am transferring videos from my web server to youtube.
Everything was working great.
The authentication was by clientLogin with my google username & password but now, all of a sudden the url (https://www.google.com/media/accounts/ClientLogin) is returning 302:

### 302 Moved

The document has moved
[here](http://www.google.com).

I saw some, but not a lot, of similar issues but nothing that solved this bizarre issue.

At first I thought that the authentication method was deprecated, but it doesn't seem so.
it is just advised not to use it.
I'm searching all day long and I'm still clueless.

**Thank you all very much.**
We have a big pilot in 5 days and it's a really big problem..

BTW
If anyone know of another method of programmatically uploading videos to youtube through an API, the clientLogin is not a problem anymore ;)

Comment: I should mention that google's example:

"curl --location https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin \
  --data 'Email=testuser&Passwd=testpw&service=youtube&source=Test' \
  --header 'Content-Type:application/x-www-form-urlencoded'"


WORKS!
The problem is supposedly in the Zend_Gdata class.
Something's change in the clientLogin auth method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The above https://www.google.com/media/accounts/ClientLogin is not valid.

It should be https://www.google.com/accounts/ClientLogin (without the 'media')
or with a google service name (like 'youtube' in my case.)

Now I know 302 really well